Installation of Ubuntu 24.04 keeps crashing can't access my backups
I did a new install of 24.04 on a new system with a USB stick that I created with Startup disc creator.
When I tried to install it the Startup disc kept crashing at different places in the installation.
After many attempts I got Ubuntu running but parts of it didn't work.
I took the computer to a friend who created his own startup disk using Rufus and he had the same problem.
He eventually did the install in safe graphics mode but parts of Ubuntu aren't working and he set it up with the superuser as 'User' whereas my setup was with 'John'.
I certainly cannot access my backups.
I get an error message and Permission Denied.
I think I need to reinstall Ubuntu with John as the superuser if I am ever going to get access to my backups.
I read elsewhere on AskUbuntu that installing 24.04 with wifi disconnected or in airplane mode results in a smoother installation.
The computer I am installing to has a wired connection to the internet so I guess I will disconnect that before installing.
I would welcome advice on my 2 problems, my identity and installation.
